# How to sort an array of google visualisation data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'm passing this array to google.visualization.arrayToDataTable function.
How can I sort this data by the month string at the first column?

```
[
 ["month", "Social", "Referral", "Direct", "All Visits"]
 ["Jan 2017", 102, 16, 3, 22,]
 ["May 2017",  13, 11, 22, 66]
 ["Apr 2017",  4, 13, 17, 59]
]
```

I tried to sort it several ways, finally getting close to sorting but the data is messed up.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using jquery/javascript for processing google chart as a widget in any container.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? (tagging your question properly can help in attracting the relevant people to look at it)

Comment: jscript or jquery

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming `data` is your posted data snipped.*

The easiest way would be this:

```
data.sort(function (a,b){
    return new Date(a[0]).getTime() - new Date(b[0]).getTime()
)
```

However, this is very inefficient, because for every compairson it will have to parse the dates over and over. It's better to parse the dates beforehand:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    data[i].unshift(new Date(data[i][0]).getTime()) // add precomputed time at the start of each datapoint
}
data.sort(function (a,b){
    return a[0] - b[0]
)
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    data[i].shift() // remove the precomputed time, as it is no longer needed
}
```